# Tracking ID missing or not displaying in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I open https://analytics.google.com/ and go to Admin section, I can't find "Tracking Id"
Notice that under the property items, **<> Tracking Info** is missing (see the attached image) We should have Tracking info section, which is missing.
How can I generate the Tracking Info or ID that starts with *UA-*

[image: Attached Image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: remember GA4 doesnt have the UA of a universal analytics account.  If you have upgraded then you wont have one.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics now defaults to creating a GA4 Property.

If you need to create a Universal Property, with a UA-XXXX-X format tracking id..

Start by creating a new property.
When you are creating that new Property, on the Property setup page, click on the blue link towards bottom of screen *Show advanced options*, that will then open up the section in the screenshot below so you can toggle on the option for a Universal property

It gives you the option of creating both property types or just a Universal Analytics property only.
Select to create just a universal property (you will be able to upgrade it to GA4 at a later date should you choose to).
[image]

If you have accidently created and do not want a GA4 Property, from the GA Admin page select the Property as you would any other property from the Property dropdown and then select it's Property Settings page and at the upper right, click the Send to Trash option to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In **Universal Analytics** just click on `Tracking Info` and then on `Tracking code`:

[image]

If you have display problems try refreshing the page or clearing your cookies and try again.

In **Google Analytics 4** you have to click on `Data Streams` and then click on the data stream desired. You will find it under `MEASUREMENT ID`:

[image]